# Identify processes that access the internet

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, networking, tcp

I need to write a program (preferably C/C++) that identifies running processes that connect to the internet, together with the domain name/URL they are trying to access.

( in case the process accesses a domain name, e.g. google.com, I need to be able to identify that domain name, not the resolved IP).

The program needs to run on Windows XP, Vista, 7.

From what I have studied, winpcap cannot identify the process.
I have searched stackoverflow on similar topics, but no satisfactory answer found...

Comment: BTW Check out the command line utility [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat).

Comment: Is it a homework? If so please tag it.

Comment: This is a very vaguely phrased question. Do you want to monitor TCP/IP traffic in general or only DNS traffic etc.?

Comment: Look at process explorer from sysinternals. This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: The purpose is very specific: write C application that can determine which process connect to the internet, and identify which URL they are connecting to - if this is done via TCPIP monitoring, or DNS monitoring, or other API, I don't care. This is a programming question, as I need to write an application, not use a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Google for tools like `tcpdump` , `tcptrace` , `tcpsplit` , `libpCap` , `wireShark`. And you will be able to look at their source code about how to capture on going TCP/IP flows and analyse them

Comment: I have already studied and tried the tools and libpcap/winpcap framework. None of them can identify the process that connects to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Detours to hook the DNS, this is a project example: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16194/Intercept-and-Rewrite-DNS-Requests-Using-Regular-E) and heres the [Detours Page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/)

Comment: wow! Detours costs $9999 if used for commercial software. Thanks, but I would need something free, or at least significantly cheaper.